# Duplicate service provider in WSO2 IS 6.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have created a service provider say "primary" is wso2 IS console and when I make any changes to that service provider, a duplicate service provider of same name is created automatically. How do I fix this?
[image: duplicate SP]

Answer (score 1):

This is already identified and fixed in IS-6.1.0. The issue occurs if you configure more than one inbound configuration type in the same service provider.
Tracked issue: https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/14950

Ideally, you shouldn't have more than one type of inbound configuration for the service provider. You can remove the unwanted configs and fix the issue of listing duplicate service providers in the list view.

Otherwise, you need to patch the change in https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/pull/4288/files pull request.

As the last option, you can go for IS-6.1.0 (new release version)